# Does LINQ to Objects caching?

Tags: linq

Does LINQ to Objects queries cache by LINQ provider when it execute for the second time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing to cache in LINQ-to-Objects, which simply uses a series of extension method calls to generate a chain (or graph) of iterators. It isn't like LINQ-to-SQL, which has to compile the graph into a SQL statement before executing it.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't. Because linq to objects it is just extensions that roll your enumerable into another enumerable or execute it immediately. It is easier to understand how linq works by reading [this article](https://timetocode.wordpress.com/2016/04/19/linq-to-objects-deep-inside-part-1/).